# Unable to get WPBakery vc_row override shortcode with additional parameters

Tags: php, wordpress, wpbakery

I've overridden the vc_row shortcode, adding additional parameters in it.

I copied the vc_row.php file under my vc-elements theme folder, and copy the value of the below extra parameter 'loggedin'.

```
add_action( 'vc_after_init', 'vc_after_init_actions' );
function vc_after_init_actions() {
  // Add Params         
    vc_add_param('vc_row', array(
      'type' => 'dropdown',
      'heading' => "Logged in/out",
      'param_name' => 'loggedin',
      'value'       => array(
        'Both'   => 'both',
        'Logged In'   => 'loggedin',
        'Logged Out'   => 'loggedout'
      ),
      'std'         => 'Both',
      'description' => "Show",
      'weight' => 1, 
  ));
}
```

This is what the vc_row.php override file returns:

```
<div data-loggedin="Both" class="vc_row wpb_row vc_row-fluid"><div class="wpb_column vc_column_container vc_col-sm-12"><div class="vc_column-inner "><div class="wpb_wrapper">
    <div class="wpb_text_column wpb_content_element ">
        <div class="wpb_wrapper">
            <p>I am text block. Click edit button to change this text. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut elit tellus, luctus nec ullamcorper mattis, pulvinar dapibus leo.</p>

        </div>
    </div>
</div></div></div></div>
```

As you can see the extra parameter loggedin is there **data-loggedin="Both"**, so it seems to work, but when I try to get this content with **get_sub_field('content')** function, I don't get the extra parameter, this is the result returned:

```
<div class="vc_row wpb_row vc_row-fluid dt-default" style="margin-top: 0px;margin-bottom: 0px"><div class="wpb_column vc_column_container vc_col-sm-12"><div class="vc_column-inner "><div class="wpb_wrapper">
    <div class="wpb_text_column wpb_content_element ">
        <div class="wpb_wrapper">
            <p>I am text block. Click edit button to change this text. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut elit tellus, luctus nec ullamcorper mattis, pulvinar dapibus leo.</p>

        </div>
    </div>
</div></div></div></div>
```

The data-loggedin="Both" parameter added is not there.

Is there anything wrong I'm doing?

Thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, eventually was my mistake. I didn't pay attention to it and the problem was that I had two different themes, so the second theme didn't have all this stuff built in it and indeed it didn't work.